# Can't use "Requests" module on Python despite installing it with pip command on mac terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I would like to use the requests module on python but I cannot use it even though I installed on my mac terminal with pip command.

Here is the result of pip show command.

```
(base) MacBook-Pro:~ *******$ pip show requests
Name: requests
Version: 2.24.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: **********
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Users/*********/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: chardet, urllib3, idna, certifi
Required-by: Sphinx, jupyterlab-server, conda, conda-build, anaconda-project, anaconda-client
```

My Python code

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/メインページ"

response= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
today = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "on_this_day"}).text

entries = today.find_all("li")
today_list = []
index = 1

for entry in entries:
    today_list.append([index, entry.get_text()])
    index += 1
print(today_list)
```

Error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Environment
VS Studio
Macbook M1 2020

Could you please help? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you share the environnment/run settings of VSStudio ? It might come from VS using a virtual environnement

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? Have you tried installing specificly for python3 with following:   pip3.8 install requests

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you share the environment/run settings of VSStudio ?　-> Im sorry I don't how I can show you the settings. Could you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? -> I heard that Python was already installed on mac but I installed it on the website. I'm not sure if there are multiple versions. When I checked mac terminal with "python --version" comand it shows Python 3.8.5.  And when I used "select Interpreter" command on VS studio, there are Python 2.7.16, 3.85 (base: conda) and 3.92.

Comment: The code you gave us is a python3 code and the pip command you ran shows us that the lib is installed for python 3.8 so my guess is that VS is running python2.7 by default. 
I am on windows so I hope it's the same for mac, you should have a blue bar at the bottom of your VS. On the left it says which version of python I run. 
check this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_environments

Comment: I think Charly is correct that your python version is wrong in VSCode. An addition if you are planning to use the Anaconda environment is that you use the conda prefix instead of pip when installing libraries.  Like the following:  "conda install <library_name>" so in your case it would be:  "conda install requests".

Comment: The results of the command that you shared are below. It was already installed. Could you elaborate what python version is wrong means? Does that mean I need to change the settings with "Python interpreter command"? Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Answer (score 0):

with

```
pip --vesrion 
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

You can see that pip installs module for python3. And with

```
pip show requests
Name: requests
Version: 2.24.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: **********
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Users/*********/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

shows that Requests is installed for python3. VS running python2 cannot find the module cause it is not installed for python2. You should set VS to use only python 3.8. You can test your script in a terminal running the command :

```
python3 ./path/to/script.py
```

To install requests for python2 (which I don't recommend using as it has passed it's end of life)

```
pip2 install requests
```

Finally, lookup virtual environment in python, it's a feature designed to separate each of your project and it's dependancy from other projects.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html